# Customizing faces of tab-line

Tags: faces, tabbar, customize-face

I've been trying to get tabs showing up on emacs, and I came across the builtin tab-mode.

I'm trying to set colors and make it look decent, and I ended up [here](https://amitp.blogspot.com/2020/06/emacs-prettier-tab-line.html), which told me to modify `tab-line-.+` with `set-face-attribute`.

So I appended this to my init.el:

```lisp
(set-face-attribute 'tab-line nil
                    ;; some omitted settings, background, foreground, font
)

(set-face-attribute 'tab-line-tab-inactive nil
                    ;; again, a bunch of omitted settings
)
```

When I load the config, I get the error: "Invalid face: tab-line-tab-inactive".

The face does seem to be present in the [`tab-line.el`](https://github.com/emacs-mirror/emacs/blob/master/lisp/tab-line.el) in the source. What's going on? Thanks!

Comment: It may be that `set-face-attribute` hasn't run yet? Perhaps this is an occasion for `with-eval-after-load`? Do you have `helm-faces`? If so what happens if you do `M-x helm-faces` and search for `tab-line`? Do you see tab-line-inactive then?

Comment: As @CalebJay suggests, these things are only defined *after* loading `tab-line.el`, so `(with-eval-after-load "tab-line.el" (set-face-attribute 'tab-line nil) (set-face-attribute 'tab-line-tab-inactive nil))` should do  the job.